# SQL Question regarding fields associated with the MAX([field]) only

Tags: sql

I'm trying to gather the entire row information associated with the MAX() of a particular field.

I essentially have several [Flight_Leg] for a unique [Shipment_ID], and each one has unique [Destination_Aiport], [Departure_Time], and [Arrival_Time]. Obviously, each [Shipment_ID] can have multiple [Flight_Leg], and each [Flight_Leg] has a unique row of information.

```
SELECT
   [Shipment_ID],           
   MAX([Flight_Leg]) AS "Final Leg",
   [Arrival_Time],
   [Destination_Airport]

FROM
    [Flight_Info]

Group By
    [Shipment_ID],
    [Arrival_Time]
```

The output is multiple lines, rather than having one unique line for [Shipment_ID]. I'm just trying to isolate the FINAL flight info for a shipment.

Comment: The results I'm trying to get, based on the SELECT query, are **Shipment_001  |   3   |   16:45    |  HKG      |**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your database, most support `window functions`.  Here's one option using `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by shipment_id order by flight_leg desc) rn
    from flight_info
    ) t
where rn = 1
```

Alternatively here's a more generic approach joining back to itself:

```
select fi.*
from flight_info fi
    join (select shipment_id, max(flight_leg) max_flight_leg
          from flight_info 
          group by shipment_id) t on fi.shipment_id = t.shipment_id
                                 and fi.flight_leg = t.max_flight_leg
```

Comment: Window functions are standard SQL and supported by all major databases.  I don't think your more "generic" approach is more generic at all.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- I'd be curious what your alternative approach would be for a more "generic" solution.  I still have the pleasure of supporting several legacy systems for our clients which do not...

Comment: . . It is the adjective "more generic".  You can call it more "old-fashioned".  Or compatible with databases whose syntax pre-dates standards set two decades ago.